# Variables appearing in the wrong order

Tags: prolog

So, I am doing a Prolog question and am having issues with how it runs. the question asks for me to "Write a predicate myencode/2 that takes the uncompressed list as a first parameter and returns the compressed list as shown as the second parameter". Which I have done, the only problem is it is printing out as number first, then letter. eg (2,'a'0, instead of ('a',2).
Provided below is my code, any advice on where i have gone wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
pack([],[]).
pack([X|Xs],[Z|Zs]) :- transfer(X,Xs,Ys,Z), pack(Ys,Zs).

transfer(X,[],[],[X]).
transfer(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|Ys],[X]) :- X \= Y.
transfer(X,[X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :- transfer(X,Xs,Ys,Zs).

myencode(L1,L2) :- pack(L1,L), transform(L,L2).
myencode([X],X):-X=[].
myencode_modified(L1,L2) :- encode(L1,L), strip(L,L2).

transform([],[]).
transform([[X|Xs]|Ys],[[N,X]|Zs]) :- length([X|Xs],N), transform(Ys,Zs).

strip([],[]).
strip([[1,X]|Ys],[X|Zs]) :- strip(Ys,Zs).
strip([[N,X]|Ys],[[N,X]|Zs]) :- N > 1, strip(Ys,Zs).
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just

```
strip([[N,X]|Ys],[[N,X]|Zs]) :- N > 1, strip(Ys,Zs).
```

which has to be

```
strip([[N,X]|Ys],[[X,N]|Zs]) :- N > 1, strip(Ys,Zs).
```

?

Comment: Yeah, that has to change, along with the transform line. Thank you for your help!